# Service dependency on Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-service

We're having a reboot issue with services (Tomcat and IIS AppPools) that are running as domain accounts, that are not able to start due to not yet having access to the domain controllers. The underlaying issue seems to be NIC teaming that takes a fair time to initialize.

The way forward seems to be adding service dependencies on IIS and Tomcat, but what should I depend on? The `Netman` service (Network Connections) seems like a likely candidate, but it is not apparent to me if this "guarantees" connectivity to the AD? Would `LanmanServer` be better?

Any other, better ways? We've had discussions about using Delayed Start, but we've seen cases where some automatic start services took a *very* long time to finish, and thus delaying the Delayed Start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is in NIC teaming initialization, I'd suggest adding a dependency on whatever service is responsible for it; there probably is a service installed by your NIC drivers which handles NIC teaming.

Another guess would be the `netlogon` service, which handles domain membership and authentication; I suspect it can start fine even if networking is not up yet, but you can give it a try.

You could also try enabling the policy `always wait for network at computer startup and logon` (either locally or via GPO), which should delay several things until the network is actually up and running, hopefully including your application services.

Comment: Thanks! It took some digging, but the Microsoft teaming is done by the service `MsLbfoProvider`. This service is only visible in the registry.